# Contract placeholders, how to express it with JSON-LD?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

The contract is a [DigitalDocument](https://schema.org/DigitalDocument) with a kind of a agreement, e.g. [Purchase and Sale Agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purchase_and_Sale_Agreement).

There are many possible ways to express the object of the contract (the *offer*), the seller, the buyer, etc. But I not see any **reference model** or "classic schema.org example" with some [convention over configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) for contracts, to express all with some "resoable tradiction".

... Please, explain me what JSON-LD (or Microdata or any other) of Schema.org I should use for a concract? There are a "example catalog" or good example of contract?

---

The JSON-LD is a dataset that will supply the placeholders of the  *contract template*...

[participants](https://schema.org/participant):

- [seller](https://schema.org/seller): an organization, but the document say "represented in this contract by this person", so it is an [Organization](https://schema.org/Organization) type with some properties as `name` and `vatID`, and a relationship with a [Person](https://schema.org/Person) (with `name` and `vatID`).
- [buyer](https://schema.org/buyer): a [Person](https://schema.org/Person) with `name` and `vatID`.

Offer: ...

JSON-LD:

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Offer",
  "participant": [
    {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "ACME (seller)",
    "recipient": {
          "@type": "Person", 
          "name": "Robert Jones (representing seller)"
      }
    },
    {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "Sarah Jane Smith (buyer)"
    }
  ]
}
```

So, how to add buyer and seller roles into the participant array? 
A contract is  a [Offer](https://schema.org/Offer)? I must to adapt the contract-semantic to the Offer-semantic? must  use *offers/offeredBy* instead *seller/buyer*? And about the "person representing an organization in the contract", it is a *recipient*?

etc.  All questions will be answered by an "example of conctract".